# Image resolutions for iPhone games using sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, ppi

I have started making iPhone games and need to know what resolution to make the images (sprites) in the game. As for now I have been making my images on paint and they are 72 ppi by default. However, I am aware that the iPhone 6 Plus has a ppi of 401. When I run my game in the IOS simulator the images do not look like they have a lower resolution than they should. So my question is: is it okay to leave the images at 72 ppi or do I need to remake them in 401? Also, do I need to make different resolution Images for each iPhone screen size or is that done automatically? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think you need @ 1x @ 2x and @ 3x size images, you don't need a larger ppi but a larger image. for more info read the apple human interface guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Comment: ignore ppi, compare pixel dimensions of device and image

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, so basically as long as I create an image in one of the scenes and make it setScale(1.0) it should be fine for all devices? Because Im not talking about app icons and launch images I understand that I need different resolutions for them, I am talking about the in game sprites